# Application multi language in kotlin using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my Android app with Kotlin minSdkVersion 26 and targetSdkVersion 28, I want to translate all my app from English to the Arabic language. In AndroidManifest.xml I add android:supportsRtl="true".
I create a "strings.xml" that contains all text fields in English, after that, I use the translation editor in Android Studio, I get the strings.xml(ar). 
In my app, I have the Main activity, that contains a bottomNavigationBar with two items: "Home", "Account". I create two fragments, AccountFragment and HomeFragment. 
In the account Fragment, I add a textView "textChangeLang": display "En" if the language is Arabic and "Ar" if the language is English and when I click on the language change.
Here's my code :

```
textChangeLang.setOnClickListener {
           langChoice = if (langChoice == "en") {
               Utility(context!!).setLocate("ar")
              /* fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                       .detach(this)
                       .attach(this)
                       .replace(R.id.frame_layout, this)
                       .commit()*/
          (activity as MainActivity).refreshMyData()
               "ar"
           } else {
               Utility(context!!).setLocate("en")
             /*  fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                       .detach(this)
                       .attach(this)
                       .replace(R.id.frame_layout, this)
                       .commit()*/
          (activity as MainActivity).refreshMyData()

               "en"
           }

       }
```

And here's the  following refreshMyData() fubction in my mainactivity :

```
 fun refreshMyData() {
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(accountFragment)
                .attach(accountFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout, accountFragment)
                .commit()
    }
```

And here's the following "setLocate" function, in the Utility class:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class Utility(val context: Context) {
.....
 fun setLocate(Lang: String) {

    val locale = Locale(Lang)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.setLocale(locale)
    context.resources?.updateConfiguration(config,
            context.resources!!.displayMetrics)
    setSavedLanguage(Lang)
}....}
```

My problem is the Account fragment is translated But the direction of fileds didn't change (the rtl option) and the title in the botton navigation bar is not translated, also the direction of icons didn't change. 
How can I correct my code to make all the fragments translated and change the direction of all fields?

Comment: please attach screenshot of expected outcome and current outcome

Comment: Are you recreating the Activity or fragment completely. It might need a forced recreation to update the UI.

Comment: I should recreate all the app, and still stay at the level of account fragment

Comment: I change some thing in my code, all the activity refresh But I want to stay at Account level UI

Comment: Did you try to recreate activity?

Comment: Yes, all the activity refresh But I want to stay at Account fragment